# Integer enum and g:select

Tags: grails, groovy

I have an Enumeration like this:

```
public enum MyEnum {
  Apple (1)
  Microsoft (2)
  IBM (4)
  Intel (8)

  int company

  MyEnum(int company) {
    this.company = company
  }
}
```

And I want a g:select box looking like this (the integer values are important in the value attribute):

```
<select>
  <option value="1">Apple</option>
  <option value="2">Microsoft</option>
  <option value="4">IBM</option>
  <option value="8">Intel</option>
</select>
```

Ok thats no problem using the g:select:

```
<g:select name="myenum" from="${MyEnum?.values()*.company}" />
```

But when I try to save the form I always get:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [MyEnum] for property myenum: no matching editors or conversion strategy found

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I use a simple integer with the inList constrain instead of the enum. Its not the same but solves my problem.

```
class MyDomain {
    int company
    static constraints = {
        company(inList: [1, 2, 4, 8])
    }
}
```

In the form:
    <g:select valueMessagePrefix="company" name="company" from="${MyDomain.constraints.company.inList}" value="${myDomainInstance?.company}"/>

Now I need to use the i18n files (messages.properties):

```
company.1=Apple
company.2=Microsoft
company.4=IBM
company.8=Intel
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
public enum MyEnum {
  Apple (1)
  Microsoft (2)
  IBM (4)
  Intel (8)

  int company

  MyEnum(int company) {
    this.company = company
  }

  String toString() { return company }
  String getKey() { name() }
}
```

and then modify the tag with

```
<g:select name="myenum" from="${MyEnum?.values()*.company}" optionKey="key" />
```

Comment: Now I get an MissingPropertyException: Message: No such property: key for class: java.lang.Integer

Comment: Because you are passing the attribute to the tag, you shoul pass the `Enum` instance itself, `MyEnum?.values()` without caring about `.company`

Comment: It's like going around in circles. When I don't use the .company my option element looks like <option value="Apple">1</option>. And I don't want that :/.